# Unable to parse json with ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I have created the following class

```
  class Contact
    def initialize(id, name, phone)
      @id = id
      @name = name
      @phone = phone
    end

    def to_json(*a)
      {
        json_class: self.class.name,
        data: { id: @id, name: @name, phone: @phone }
      }.to_json(*a)
    end

    def self.json_create(o)
      new( o[:data][:id], o[:data][:name], o[:data][:phone] )
    end
  end
```

I can now convert it to json using this

```
Contact.new(1,'nik',10).to_json
 => "{\"json_class\":\"Contact\",\"data\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"nik\",\"phone\":10}}"
```

But it explodes with an error when I call `JSON.parse` on the it.

```
JSON.parse(Contact.new(1,'nik',10).to_json)
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):44:in `json_create'
```

I picked up the syntax from [this](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/) tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the symbols in your `json_create` method.

```
def self.json_create(o)
  new( o['data']['id'], o['data']['name'], o['data']['phone'] )
end
```

Comment: That did the trick, could you tell me why what i did is wrong, I was under the impression that symbols and strings could be used interchangeably and symbols had better performance.

Comment: Symbols and strings are different objects.
Symbols are always a reference to the same object, whereas strings are new objects each time referenced (unless stored in a variable).

Comment: What @AndréSantosdeMedeiros said is correct. The behavior you are thinking of is something that comes with Rails, which provides a [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) that lets you use either the symbol or string form of the key to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as_json` instead of `to_json`.